# Decode Hebrew text with unidentified encoding

Tags: character-encoding

I have a very old Hebrew text file that I don't know what software was created and what its encoding is. The text appears to me like gibberish.
The text looks like this:

```
enter code here    $€∆«¬ Õ–€–‘«¸ Õ–« ¬Œ∆ ‹«Œ≈«‹ √“À “…¨ ©«¬Œ∆ ‹«Œ≈«‹ ∆€–Àœ®¨ «–∆ €∆…»À⁄ «À«Œ≈ \
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could figure out the coding for me and how to translate it to Hebrew.

Comment: Please  [edit] the question and add output from `powershell -command "(Get-Content 'path_to_your_file' -Encoding Byte -TotalCount 200) -join ','"` or  a few lines from (the beginning of) `pwsh -command "([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes( 'path_to_your_file')) -join ','"`.

Comment: is this the content or the name of the file?
where did you copy the text from?
which operating system is this on?

Comment: this is content, i copy the text from Textedit app and the operating system is macOS.